# Backfill scheduled Query in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

I have the following scheduled query which creates a file that contains unnested records. It is setup to use a partition date.

When I run a back fill on this query, more records are added to the most recent date, previous partitions are not updated. What am I doing wrong? Should the backfill not apply to  `FORMAT_DATE('%y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

```
SELECT  user_pseudo_id, event_bundle_sequence_id, event_timestamp, event_date,  event_server_timestamp_offset, parameters.key as parameters,
  parameters.value.string_value as parameters_string_value, parameters.value.int_value as parameters_int_value, parameters.value.float_value as parameters_float_value,
  parameters.value.double_value as parameters_double_value,
  FROM 

(SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_bundle_sequence_id, event_timestamp, event_date, event_server_timestamp_offset, event_params FROM  'xxx.xxx.events_20*'

WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))),
        UNNEST(event_params) as parameters
```

Comment: You didn't tell how is your table partitioned. Is it possible that you have an **ingestion time** partitioned table?

Comment: Yes it is partitioned on event_date

Comment: Could you take a look at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#ingestion_time, to tell if your partitioned table is a regular partition table or an injestion time partitoned table?

Comment: It says that Ingestion-time partitioned tables include a pseudo column named _PARTITIONTIME - I can't see this, so I assume a regular partition table